# Android service is briefly null on start/resume

Tags: java, android

I have a background service that manages pub/sub to a 3rd party API.

I set up the service like this:

```
 public ServiceConnection myServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            myService = ((ThirdPartyService.Binder)binder).getService();
        }
 }
```

Then in my activity onCreate method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdPartyService.class);
bindService(intent);
```

When the activity loads the service is initially null.

```
public void onStart() {
    myService.doSomething();  //is null for a few hundred milliseconds
}
```

I have to put in a delay (500ms minimum) before using the service.

The question is, is there a callback method/strategy that can be used to trigger when the service is available, in lieu of an arbitrary delay?

Comment: This is a big code smell. You really shouldn't have business logic in your activity. Anyway, why not execute that call into the service's `onStartCommand()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The service will be available when the `onServiceConnected` callback is invoked and in that moment you have the guarantee that the `myService` variable will be not null.

Just trigger everything that need to consume your ThirdPartyService API service after that.
I also expect `myServiceConn` defined in the activity.

Comment: Works on startup, but when the app is sent to background and then resumed, the service is still connected. Therefore, onServiceConnected is not fired again. Since I disconnect from the API in this scenario, I need to reconnect to the API, and need the service available, which is delayed.

Comment: I expect you unbind the service before going background, right?

Comment: No, I only unbind in onDestroy;

Comment: ok so please try to unbind the service on `onStop` and see if the `onServiceConnected` callback is invoked when the activity is resumed. Hope this helps.

Comment: @lilbiscuit Lino is right here. You want to bind/unbind at complementary points. Android docs recommend `onStart()/onStop()`. `onStop()` is called as soon as the activity leaves the screen. If it is not called, that means you crashed. You may use your `mService` reference in-between `onServiceConnected()` and `unbindService()`.

Comment: @greeble31  I wish it were so, but bind/unbind in `onStart()/onStop()` are not triggering `onServiceConnected / onServiceDisconnected `. So far the only working method is a separate thread waiting for service to be not null.

Comment: @lilbiscuit If it is a local, in-process `ThirdPartyService`, then `onServiceDisconnected()` is not called under any circumstances (could you clarify the nature of the service in your question). `onServiceConnected()` will be called so long as A.) The `Service` has successfully started and B.) you have returned control to the framework in order to wait for the call.

Comment: @greeble31 My code is derived from [this activity code](https://github.com/pubnub/webinar-android-intro/blob/master/app/src/main/java/intro/android/webinar/pubnub/com/androidintrowebinar/MainActivity.java) and [this service code](https://github.com/pubnub/webinar-android-intro/blob/master/app/src/main/java/intro/android/webinar/pubnub/com/androidintrowebinar/PubNubService.java) .

Comment: @lilbiscuit Looks like it's "local in-process". If it's all one app -- if the `Service` is defined in your AndroidManifest.xml -- then that's the case. I'm thinking maybe you did not return from `onStart()` to wait for the call.

Answer (score -2):

Yep! Just add this:

```java
while (variableThatIsAProblem == null) {
/* If you wanna put a system.out.println(not ready yet) sorta thing here do that otherwise don't bother */
}
Other code
```

Comment: This will just get stuck in the `while` loop infinitely. Perhaps a wait/notify modification...

Comment: I guess he means `while (myService == null);` Why would it get stuck infinitely? You said myService eventually gets assigned.

Comment: In any case this solution is bad because it tries to fix the manifestation of the problem instead of the problem itself.

Comment: @m0skit0  `while` appears to be blocking. Putting it in a separate thread does work, however. To your point...is it ideal?

Comment: In my opinion you shouldn't be waiting for a variable to cease to be null ever. If that happens, you're structuring your code badly, aka a code smell. Please see my comment on your question.

Comment: This solution will block `Service` creation; `Service.onCreate()`/`onServiceConnected()` will never be called, if this is executed on the UI thread. You must return control to the framework before the service creation/binding state can advance.